# Salvar formulário XHTML como PDF

Tags: html, xhtml, pdf

Estou criando uma página de relatório via XHTML, têm opção para visualizar o formulário e gostaria de adicionar um botão para fazer download desse formulário como PDF.

Estava tentando utilizar o DomPDF para fazer isso, mas aparece uma página php com o os códigos ao invés de aparecer um PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando asp.net MVC, o package RazorPDF pode te ajudar:
http://nyveldt.com/blog/page/razorpdf

Ou veja neste site também:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/163462/How-to-do-xHTML-to-xHTML-Transformations-for-PDF-C

Comment: Pior que não estou utilizando ele :/